# Laravel 5.2 mailgun error bad request

Tags: php, laravel, email, request, mailgun

I'm currently working on some app based on Laravel 5.2. I need to send email with reset password link to the user and I'm using mailgun. Everything is working fine when I send email to the mail on which mailgun is registered. But it fails when it is any other email address.

Error says:

> ClientException in RequestException.php line 71:
>   Client error response [url] https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandbox*******************************.mailgun.org/messages.mime [status code] 400 [reason phrase] BAD REQUEST

I've tried many solutions but none of them works. Any idea why it happens? Maybe is it caused by localhost?
I am using:

- Laravel 5.2
- Mailgun
- WAMP as my localhost
- guzzlehttp v.4.0

Controller function:

```
public function sendEmail() {
    $sent = Mail::send('mails.test', [], function ($message) {
        $message->to('xxxxxxx@windowslive.com','somename');
        $message->subject("Activate Your Account");
        $message->getSwiftMessage();
    });
    if ($sent === 0) {
        return redirect('/')
            ->withErrors('Failed to send activation email.');
    }
    return redirect('/')
        ->withSuccess('Mail was sent.');
}
```

env data:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mailgun
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailgun.org
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=postmaster@sandbox*****************************.mailgun.org
MAIL_PASSWORD=**********************
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

MAILGUN_DOMAIN=sandbox*****************************.mailgun.org
MAILGUN_SECRET=key-*****************************
```

File: conf/mail.php is configured as .env data

Route:

```
Route::get('auth/send','AuthController@sendEmail');
```

Button:

```
<a href="{{action('AuthController@sendEmail')}}" class="btn btn-danger">Test mail</a>
```

Comment: Could you post the code which are you trying?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailgun.org` from the `.env` and give a try. I faced the same situation in the past and removing `MAIL_HOST` worked for me. New `.env` configuration would look like

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mailgun
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=postmaster@sandbox*****************************.mailgun.org
MAIL_PASSWORD=**********************
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

MAILGUN_DOMAIN=sandbox*****************************.mailgun.org
MAILGUN_SECRET=key-*****************************
```

after this, run `php artisan config:cache` and `php artisan config:clear` from the `command line` and check whether mail works or not.